# How can I refactor my 2d unity movement script to resolve the behavioral issues I have?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is the code I've written for my 2D movement:

```
void HandleInput()
{
    float verticalMoveAmount = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    float horizontalMoveAmount = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (facingRight)
    {
        transform.Translate(horizontalMoveAmount, verticalMoveAmount, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Translate(-horizontalMoveAmount, verticalMoveAmount, 0);
    }

    if (horizontalMoveAmount > 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (horizontalMoveAmount < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && hasBall)
    {
        Shoot();
    }   
}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

I have the below problems though:

1. I have a Cinemachine virtual camera following the player around. However, whenever the player changes direction they vanish from the camera view. I think this is something to do with the Flip(), but I don't know why or how to fix it.
2. The if statement for if facingRight where I have to use negative movement on the horizontal axis, this feels like a really poor way to handle it, but if I don't do that I can't move left when the player changes directions to the left. Is there a better way I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can solve your behavioral issues by refactoring a unity script... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 1) my guess is that since you rotate the object by 180° you are looking at the backface of it -> it is not being rendered due to backface culling.

To 2) since you rotate the object by 180° it's local coordinate system is now pointing in the other direction. Note that by default [`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) works in the **local** coordinate system. If you want to rather use global axes then simply pass in

```
transform.Translate(horizontalMoveAmount, verticalMoveAmount, 0, Space.World);
```

---

In general simply assuming you are using a [`SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) which is the most common thing for 2D games you should rather use the property [`SpriteRenderer.flipX`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html) and not rotate your object at all. This would solve both issues at the same time

---

So together your code could be simply

```
public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

void HandleInput()
{
    var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    // ensure that diagonal movement isn't faster
    input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(input, 1f);

    var movement = input * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(movement, Space.World);
    // basically the same now as
    //transform.position += movement;
    
    if (input.x != 0)
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = input.x < 0;
    }

    if (hasBall && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Shoot();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So I tried the above code, but my sprite won't actually flip in the game. I can see the flipx property is being ticked, but it always faces to the right.

Comment: Also in the above code, should I still use my old horizontalMoveAmount & verticalMoveAmount variables in transform.translate? Or should I be using input somehow?

Comment: @Cypher236 oh sorry yeah you should use `movement` ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I still have a slight issue with flipping but this is amazingly useful, I've implemented the above and I'll try and find out what's happening with the flipping!